# Error Using "Build Virtual Raster"

Tags: qgis

i'm new using QGIS (my version is 2.14.9) and received multi ortophotos (Supposedly Georeferenced in Datum 73) and so i'm trying to put them all  together using "Build Virtual Raster" following the Procedures described in [Joining several raster files using QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/25499/joining-several-raster-files-using-qgis)
but i get the following error menssage:

> "Warning 6 gdalbuildvrt does not support ungeoreferenced image"

What i did was "add layer" for which one of the orthos and sellected Datum 73 and then, when using the build virtual raster, instead of using "Choose input directory instead of files" i had choosen the option to use the layers i had added.

From what i can understand QGIS is not assuming that the ortophotos i have are georreferenced, but i don't know what i'm missing, can anyone please help?

PS: i have checked if the ortophotoss are georrefereced using AUTOCAD CIVIL 3D and, when choosing Datum 73 everything was fine.

Answer (score 1):

Well to be honest i don't know what i did different from before but the problem was solved.

1. Saved the tiff's with associated .tfw file - before i only had the tiff's (maybe that's the problem?)
2. In Miscellaneous -> Build Virtual Raster -> Choose the input directory to the file with the data (.tiff and .tfw)
3. Choose everything showed in the post [Joining several raster files using QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/25499/joining-several-raster-files-using-qgis) plus the CRS (datum 73)
4. And then it was done perfectly.
5. I also did the "build overviews (pyramids)" because the .vrt file was too large and the qgis was very slow, it took me almost 1 hour to complete but now it's much better.

Thank's anyway,

Regards