# Exporting a GeoTIFF in Float16 format

Tags: qgis, gdal, qgis-3, floating-point

I'm trying to merge large raster files (DEM's) together but I run into memory errors using the 'Raster Merge' tool in QGIS 3.8.

I suspect the issue is mainly the high amount of precision in the float32 data format for each pixel. Therefore if I could translate/convert the format into half/float16 format I should be able to do this.

Unfortunately I don't see an option to export GeoTIFF's into this format in the 'Raster Translate' tool or otherwise.

Edit: I need a few decimal places of precision - ideally 3. The rasters are DEM's that are accurate to about 8-10cm, so any decimals past 3 are nonsense and just eat up memory.

Comment: 16-bit float doesn't appear to be an exceedingly useful format, with just three places of accuracy (1/3 is 0.333251953125). In theory, GDAL 2.2 and higher support it, but most DEMs I've ever used were signed 16-bit, so truncating values for no storage gain doesn''t seem like a likely solution. This appears to be an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), where your question is about an unlikely implementation instead of the root problem (memory errors).  You would likely get a better solution by changing the question.

Comment: Perhaps you could create a virtual raster: https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/25499/81764

Answer (score 2):

There is a `DISCARD_LSB` option for GeoTIFFs that could be useful in conjunction with compression. For example the following call will compress `input.tif` to `output.tif` using the `DEFLATE` algorithm with a floating point predictor (`2`) and discard the 2 least significant bits:

```
gdal_translate input.tif output.tif -co COMPRESS=DEFLATE -co PREDICTOR=2 DISCARD_LSB=2
```

Answer (score 2):

For gdal version >= 2.2, there is an option `NBITS=16` to get half-precision floating point output. So, something like:

```
gdal_translate -co NBITS=16 input.tif output.tif
```